# What can I do about newspaper with poor referencing?

Tags: citations, social-media

Newspapers often like to report on new scientific advancements.
They often do a terrible job.
They may sensationalise the story.
Or confuse a project proposal/preliminary study with a result.

We can perhaps forgive them, and take the blame on ourselves for not making papers clear enough for them to understand.
Or not. This question is **not** about inaccuracies in reporting however.
**This question is about poor referencing of the scientific article they are talking about -- making it hard to track down the original source.**

Because of the often low quality of the newspaper reporting, it is important to be able to find and read the original scientific article.

When you tell a fellow about a new paper that came out, 
you are bare minimum include the title, and the names of the authors,
and generally the year, and publication venue too.

Recently I have seen major newspapers failing to do this.

For example
The news paper article:

- [John Ross, "Anxiety epidemic hits the rich and the young", *The Australian*, 6 june 2016](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/nation/anxiety-epidemic-hits-the-rich-and-the-young/news-story/b7001843239fde140ec679a2dff12edd?utm_source=The%20Australian)

Is talking about:

- [Olivia Remes, Carol Brayne, Rianne van der Linde and Louise Lafortune, "A systematic review of reviews on the prevalence of anxiety disorders in adult populations", *Brain and Behavior* 2016](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/brb3.497/epdf)

But all it mentions is the name and affiliation of the first author, and the name of the journal -- an even these are hidden in the text, rather than in a nice block.

We can compare this against a specialized scientific news source:

- [unknown author, "Women and people under the age of 35 at greatest risk of anxiety", *Science Bulletin*, 6 June 2016](http://sciencebulletin.org/archives/1855.html)

Which gives full detail, including a DOI, in a nice source block at the end.
I've also seen this sometimes in newspapers, but it is not ubiquitous. 
Sadly, the newspaper I mention above (The Australian) is probably the most reputable mainstream newspapers in my country (if you know a better one I'm interested).

---

**What can I, as a concerned** (read: busybody) **academic, with no affilation to the article being written about, do to work towards countering the poor practices of these newspapers?**

Right now, what I am doing is everytime someone links to a news report on social media I hunt down the original paper, and link them to it by commenting on there post.
This solves the problem for one person, and for people who follow them.

But can I be countering it overall?
Is it worth writing to the newspaper, providing a request that the clean up there act?
Should I perhaps contact the authors of the paper, informing them of the (petty)  injustice the paper is doing to their work, by not referencing it correctly?

Comment: Perhaps a follow up question  might be worth having with regard to blogs.

Comment: In my experience, newspapers hardly ever list the title of a paper they mention; this isn't new.  Good ones will usually give the author and the name of the journal, and perhaps the publication date ("appearing in the current issue of *Nature*").

Comment: Indeed it is not new, but long term bad practices is still bad practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that most newspapers don't have their own "on-staff" technical writers to handle such articles, I doubt that writing a newspaper and pleading with them to include more information about the publication will be very helpful. More importantly, providing large amounts of technical detail is frankly not what a newspaper is meant for. The best you could reasonably expect is that the web page for the article might include a link to the journal page. But you should probably not expect full details of the publication on the web page itself.

For sites and publications like [*Ars Technica*](http://www.arstechnica.com), the situation is different, since they're much more science-oriented. Then it would be reasonable to politely email the author of the article you're interested and request that the additional information be added.

Comment: ... or post a comment asking for the info to be added to the article, if it's posted online.